# Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID failed (ASP.NET framework c#)

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api

I have added a dll library inside my ASP.NET framework c# project and I have created a `ASP.NET FRAMEWORK API CONTROLLER` in this `ASP.NET FRAMEWORK` c# project. 
Inside this `API CONTROLLER` class, I have created a function called `fnGetTerminalInfo()` that instantiates an object of the dll library interface class.

I tried to run the API controller 
`localhost:xxxxx/api/conGetTerminalInfoAPI/fnGetTerminalInfo` in a localhost and it works perfectly.
However, after deploying the project to IIS and run the API controller using this url `<ip address>:<port number>/api/conGetTerminalInfoAPI/fnGetTerminalInfo` in a browser, I received an error that says

> Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {5DC9FDA1-B975-49BF-8A89-05068714BAFD} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).
>   
>   System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException

However when I removed the code(s) that instantiates an object of the dll library interface class from the function `fnGetTerminalInfo()`, the error disappeared.

Does anyone know what causes the error? Thank You :) Looking forward to your answer :)

Comment: 64bit application? (Check project settings)

Comment: Your code uses a COM component that isn't registered. Register the component on the server. Note that this might not be possible (e.g shared web hosts), in which case you will need a different approach.

Comment: Alternatively: Registration-free COM: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fh1h056h(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Ofiris, it says target any cpu, including x64.

Comment: possible duplicate from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17985653/class-not-registered-error

Comment: @Antoni Choose x86 as the platform target and retry, your DLL might be a 32bit component

Comment: @Dai, but it will still be possible using IIS right?

Comment: @Ofiris, after changing from "target any cpu" to "x86" and reload the url <ip address>:<port number>/api/conGetTerminalInfoAPI/fnGetTerminalInfo in a browser, it gives me this error: System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'ContactlessPaymentAPI' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.

Comment: @Ofiris, it also says WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].