# Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a web application which is used to send email. In this application, I am reading data from an Excel file and send email.
This is working fine in the local system, but not working after uploading on the server.

I have received the following errors

> Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID
>   {00024500-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following
>   error:
>
> 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154
>   (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).

How can I fix it?

Comment: link may help you.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17985653/class-not-registered-error

Comment: @pankajkumarsingh try my answer below .

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**  to this badimageformatexception is setting the 'Enable32bitApplications' to 'True' in IIS Apppool properties for the right apppool.