# An error "Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID" upon using a third party tool

Tags: c#, xml, xslt, altova

I am trying to do an XSLT transformation using Altova RaptorXML Server2018  that I downloaded now for a trail. I get an error saying "Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {F02635AC-3BB8-4E68-9066-CAE1D218E3F6} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception). The file I downloaded is a 64bit version. Please let me know the solution for this. I use Visual studio 2015for my C# implementation

Comment: It didn't get installed properly.  did you run as admin when installing?  See : http://manual.altova.com/RaptorXML/raptorxmlserver/index.html?rxcomnet_aboutdotnet.htm

Comment: I uninstalled and installed as admin again . I installed the 64-bit version. I see the dll in the GAC. I referenced the same in my project. No luck. Please provide me a solution. Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: Are you getting same error? (Class Not registered).  Did follow all the instruction in the link I provided?  Does it work if you run as admin?  Did you check permissions? :  If you receive an access error, check that permissions are correctly set. Go to Component Services and give permissions to the same account that runs the application pool containing RaptorXML.

Comment: @jdweng please let me know how to give permissions to the same account that runs the application pool containing RaptorXML

Comment: Right click and choose "Run as administrator" (one-time / ad hoc)

or right click and choose properties > Compatibility > check "Run this program as administrator" (set it permanently; can also be handy for setting this property on a shortcut (which is basically what Start menu items are))

Comment: are u talking about setting as admin to visual studio? . that I have done already

Comment: +  ex {"Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {F02635AC-3BB8-4E68-9066-CAE1D218E3F6} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG))."} System.Exception {System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException} .. This is my exception when I initialize altova object

Comment: Is you project set for x86 and Any?  I would delete the bin folder on you project and recompile.  If you change the project settings sometimes not all the files get recompiled due to the dependencies.  At this point of time I assume the dll got registered properly and now it has something to do with your project.  See : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17985653/class-not-registered-error

Comment: Ya . I set x64 and IISApppool enable 32 bit. It worked :) Thank uu