# How do I find which unregistered DLL is implementing the COM object?

Tags: c#, dll, com

I have a C# application that is interoperate with MATLAB. When i deploy my application on the target system and when MATLAB gets called up from my C# application (for performing its functionalities), i get this error:

[image: The DLL that implements the COM object is not registered]

I want to help to find out the DLL file that might be unregistered and then register it.

Comment: Look for that CLSID on your system or google for id. It seems to be matlab application. It might be an x64 vs x86 problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17985653/class-not-registered-error

Answer (score 3):

On the (dev) machine where the app is working properly you can find this CLSID in the registry (HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\ {you guid...}) and see the DLL used under InprocServer32 key.
To view/edit registry use regedit.

Comment: IMHO you should mention there are 2 classes registries: the 32bit and 64bit one (Wow6432Node etc.). One should search both.

Comment: Pavel Aristarkhov thanks i was able to find the CLSID in the registry you mentioned. But where can i see the InprocServer32 key to see which DLL was used? Also, once i find it, how can i register it on the target machine?

Comment: It also can be LocalServer32 key. For example: 
https://pasteboard.co/KhEJl1k.png

Comment: For second question. Depending of DLL type (.NET, raw, etc.) it can be registerred by regasm .NET utility or installed on machine by other ways (by own installer). There are many options...

Comment: May be you referenced some of ActiveX (or like) in your C# project? Then you have to deploy it with your app.

Comment: Well the LocalServer32 shows "Matlab.application"

Comment: I think it need to install something like MatLab SDK. I do not know. Maybe it will be useful https://www.intechopen.com/chapters/39341.