# Excel Generation in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

I have Error for Excel Generation.

Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {00024500-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).

It works fine on my local machine.

Comment: Did you check [Resolving HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1496214/how-to-solve-com-exception-class-not-registered-exception-from-hresult-0x80040)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error "The Class not registered" is because the COM object is missing on the computer.

The PIA just are the assemblies that allow you to call the Office COM object model from .NET.

You need to install the Office on your server to fix.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you use excel for excel file generation. And may be you have no excel on your server?
I recommend you to pay attention to [OpenXML sdk](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DocumentFormat.OpenXml/)  to generate office 2007+ documents. It don't need excel on computer to generate excel file.

Comment: I install Primary Interop Assemblies on my server for office.

Comment: This might an issue when you don't have an installed MS Office on the machine. I suggest to use other libraries that can work without an Installed MS Office. [ClosedXML](https://closedxml.codeplex.com/) is a good one

Answer (score 0):

We had a lot of problems with Excel and Interop and one day found [EPPlus](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EPPlus/). Unlike Excel Interop it works standalone and has a pretty decent API to read and write Excel files.

I know it is not the answer to your question, but probably the solution to your problem!