# ATL Server works in IDE does not work via cmd

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, com, server, atl

I working on an ATL Service project, an exe (out of process) NOT a DLL, and have created my COM object. When I test the Server in Visual Studio 2015 with a test client application it works with no problems.
When I install the server using, as recommended by [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/74y2334x.aspx),

```
YourEXE.exe /Service
```

The server installs and is visible in Services however when I use the same test client application I get the REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG Class not registered error (Please note [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1496214/how-to-solve-com-exception-class-not-registered-exception-from-hresult-0x80040) does not solve this).

Any ideas on a potential problems? I have only added the COM object and have not modified the rest of template in anyway. Have I possibly missed something?

Comment: You can debug the registration process (`YourEXE.exe /RegServer`).  Are you running the registration with elevated privileges (it writes to HKLM)?

Comment: How do I debug it? It is being run with elevated privileges but writes to HKCR instead of HKLM.

Comment: Why the downvote? A comment would have been helpful!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

We found the problem. The .rgs file had the wrong GUID in it. 
This is unusual as the file was auto generated.

Comment: Why the downvote? A comment would have been helpful!