# C# .Net Application crashes for Colleague, 'Class not registered'

Tags: c#

I published the 64bit Release Version on Windows 7 in VS 2017 Community and it runs fine for me, but my friend on Windows 10 can't run it.  He is receiving the error that there is a 'class not registered'.

Is he missing a dependency that I'm not?  Is there a way to include the dependency in the package?

Comment: What assembly is the exception pointing to?

Comment: Are you using a COM component? If so, is it registered on his machine? See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1496214/how-to-solve-com-exception-class-not-registered-exception-from-hresult-0x80040)

Comment: It's pointing to Microsoft.Speech.Synthesis, which is enabled as a reference.  Both my installed version and the released program are 64bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never got a truly satisfying answer, but the solution was to have him install everything I did when I first built the thing.  Very tedious.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18081233)

Comment: I am the author, this was the answer to my problem.  It might not help prevent the issues, but it is a fix.  The question has already gone unanswered for a month.

Comment: There was a problem, the answer makes it go away.  How could that possibly be unhelpful?

Comment: Your error is very generic and hard to discover, your problem description very sparse your resolution even more, and the post got only a few clicks (mostly from reviewers I guess).

Comment: Indeed.  Problem was still.  Solved it is.

How error occurred?  Will never know.