# Acces Outlook via Visual Basic error

Tags: vb.net, winforms, outlook, clsid, interopservices

I'm trying to create a program which retrieves all emails from Outlook's(2007 desktop version) Inbox and puts them into a DataGridView.

Code:

```
Imports Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook

Public Class Form1
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim dt As DataTable
    Try
        Dim app As Outlook.Application = New Outlook.Application()
        Dim ns As Outlook.[NameSpace] = app.GetNamespace("MAPI")
        Dim inbox As Outlook.MAPIFolder = ns.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox)
        ns.SendAndReceive(True)
        dt = New DataTable("Inbox")
        dt.Columns.Add("Subject", GetType(String))
        dt.Columns.Add("Sender", GetType(String))
        dt.Columns.Add("Body", GetType(String))
        dt.Columns.Add("Date", GetType(String))
        DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
        For Each item As Object In inbox.Items
            If TypeOf item Is Outlook.MailItem Then
                Dim item1 As Outlook.MailItem = CType(item, Outlook.MailItem)
                dt.Rows.Add(New Object() {item1.Subject, item1.Sender, item1.HTMLBody, item1.SentOn.ToLongDateString() & "" + item1.SentOn.ToLongTimeString()})
            End If
        Next
        MessageBox.Show("done")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.[Error])
    End Try
End Sub
End Class
```

When I try to Build the project I'm getting the follow error:

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80040154): Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {0006F03A-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG))

**UPDATE**

I've changed the Compiler CPU to x86 and x64, this does not solve the error.

[Target platform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QzWnE.png)

Comment: does your code? because i've trying to do something like this but i couldn't find any perfect silution...where did u get this from?

Comment: I dont know if this code works, since I cant run the program because of the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem causing the error was that both applications(VS2015 and MS Office 2007) were not running under the same rights. Open both applications with same rights(administrator or user) and the application will work. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

What is the target platform of your application? Is it a x86-based application?

The problem (probably) that the COM class (which is in a 32 bit COM dll) is registered, but since the application is running in 64 bit mode it won't find a correct registration (32 bit and 64 bit COM servers are registered separately).

Also you may find the [How to solve COM Exception Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG))? page helpful.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1496214/how-to-solve-com-exception-class-not-registered-exception-from-hresult-0x80040)

Comment: I've changed the compiler mode of VS2017 to x64 and x86 and tried both of them. Still getting the error.

Comment: Try to repair MS Office. Looks like something is wrong with your windows registry records, they are corrupted.

Comment: I've repaired MS Office aswell, not deleted and reinstalled yet. U think deleting and reinstalling can help?

Answer (score 0):

try this method and Send arguments to it such as Subject,body,Toaddress,filename...Im Sure this will works..

```
Private Sub SendfromOutlook(sSubject As String, sBody As String, sTo As String, sFilename As String)
    Dim oApp As Interop.Outlook._Application
    oApp = New Interop.Outlook.Application
    Dim oMsg As Interop.Outlook._MailItem

    Dim strS As String()
    strS = sTo.Split(",")
    For i As Integer = 0 To strS.Length - 1

        oMsg = oApp.CreateItem(Interop.Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem)
        oMsg.Subject = sSubject
        oMsg.Body = sBody
        oMsg.To = strS(i)

        Dim str As String = sFilename

        If sFilename <> "" Then


            Dim sBodyLen As Integer = Int(sBody.Length)
            Dim oAttachs As Interop.Outlook.Attachments = oMsg.Attachments
            Dim oAttach As Interop.Outlook.Attachment
            oAttach = oAttachs.Add(str, , sBodyLen)

        End If

        oMsg.Send()

    Next
    MessageBox.Show("EMail Sent Successfully!", "Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK)
    ClearAll()
End Sub
```

here I use To address with "," to send Multiple mails at a time..thats why i just split it and used this functions as a looping one ( Dim strS As String() and
    strS = sTo.Split(","))

Comment: Nice code! But its not answering my question. My main issue was that i got the error, this is fixed now. I used Outlook and VS2015 on different rights(user and administrator), when i run both on administrator the program works. Thanks anyway!