# Unable to open Windows form ( .vb ) in visual studios 2010

Tags: c#, forms, visual-studio

[image]

I'm getting attached error while trying to open form in VS2010.

NOTE : when i was working in office network this issue was not there, now that i'm working from home connecting to my own network due to corona virus advisory, i'm facing this error.
I'm unable to run as well, getting below error while running :

An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in STERILE TUBE FUSER - DRY.exe

Additional information: An error occurred creating the form. See Exception.InnerException for details.  The error is: Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG))

With break and continue button.
Please help.

Comment: Have you already looked at the following question and its answers? [How to solve COM Exception Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG))?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1496214/6122062)

Comment: It looks like you are trying to open a VB6 file which is more than a decade older than VS 2010

Comment: No, it doesn't, actually the same settings along with same windows bit it was working fine in office, now i have not changed anything, sudden;y it stopped working after connecting from my home network.