CorelDRAW.Application class not registered VBA CorelDRAW
I'm trying to make a program in Excel's VBA editor that interacts with Corel. When I try to run Corel in the COM via this line:
Set cdrApp= CreateObject("CorelDRAW.Application")
I get "Runtime error '-2147418113': class not registered"
Here is some more relevant code for context:
Sub mySubroutine(ByRef inArray As Variant)
     Dim cdrApp As CorelDRAW.Application
     
     Set cdrApp = CreateObject("CorelDRAW.Application")

     'Lots of irrelevant code here

End Sub

I'm also receiving a compile error at Dim cdrApp As CorelDRAW.Application "User-defined type not defined." For the time being I've just declared this as an Object as this is a less immediate issue.
My thinking originally was that something was wrong with the library. At first, I just had "Corel - CorelDRAW 24.5 Type Library" selected in my references, but I went into the Corel files and added every single tlb file I could find.
Then I read probably close to 40 discussion posts between the ones on here and on the Corel dev community; tried changing the datatype to As VGCore.Application; tried hacking the CreateObject method by doing CreateObject("", "CorelDRAW.Application"); tried doing Set cdrApp = "CorelDRAW.Application"; tried doing Set cdrApp = New CorelDRAW.Application; Went into the services manager and double checked the progID; As well as few other frugal things.
And, of course, I looked at the API documentation for CorelDRAW '23 24.5.
Thanks for any help.

Edit: Some more things I have tried that didn't work:
Set cdrApp = CreateObject("CorelDRAW.Application.24") Since the CurVer key is that; Double checked the registry to ensure CorelDRAW.Application was registered (Thanks @SimonMourier); Tried reinstalling CorelDRAW, tried running everything on a 2nd PC, reinstalled corel, ensured corel's installation contained the proper settings to enable VBA

Could well be an x86 vs x64 issue, ie: COM client runs as x86 process while COM server (exe here) is only registered for x64 processes clients, or the reverse

@SimonMourier How could I check this?

Make sure both applications (here seems to be Excel.exe and CorelDRAW.Application not sure what the .exe is) share the same bitness (both x86 or both x64). You can also use procmon and filter by .exe and regisry access https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon

@SimonMourier Thanks for your help, but both processes are x64.

"Class not registered" means the client cannot find the clsid of the progid it's looking for. So if they're both x64, it means the COM server (here "CorelDRAW.Application") is not registered in the x64 registry for some reason. Use procmon to make sure

@SimonMourier I've never used anything like procmon before, lol. Could you give me some more instructions to help me understand? I really appreciate the help.

Have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/a/32460838/403671. Or open regedit check at HKCR\CorelDraw.Application then HKCR\CorelDraw.Application\CLSID (get the guid) then HKCR\CLSID<guid> then HKCR\CLSID<guid>\LocalServer32 (for an exe COM server). If something is not there it means CorelDraw has not registered its COM server for some reason. I don't have CorelDraw so difficult to help more.

Dim cdrApp As CorelDRAW.Application is early binding. You need to add reference (VBE Tools>References, check CorelDRAW library) before run the code. Microsoft documentation:

Early and Late Binding (Visual Basic)


@SimonMourier Ok, I followed your instructions for the regedit method. There is something at that location. Its value is: "c:\Program Files\Corel\CorelDRAW Graphics Suite 2023\Programs64\CorelDRW.exe" /Automation Should I be using CorelDRW instead of CorelDRAW in my code?

Not at all, CorelDRAW.Application is the progid and seems correct. The registration seems ok, the program seems x64. Are you 100% sure the client is x64? Also are you sure the exact error is "-2147418113': class not registered" ? because -2147418113 is 0x8000FFFF, ie: E_UNEXPECTED, not 0x80040154, ie REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG "class not registered"

@SimonMourier Could it be the dll file? In the InprocHandler32 key, the dll listed as default is ole32.dll, a file that isn't included in the program files of CorelDRAW. Could it be that it's pulling an incorrect dll?

No that's normal completely normal, apparently CorelDraw is correcly registered, you can compare with other COM exe servers like Office ones (progids Word.Document, Excel.Sheet, etc) but it's very similar. You should look elsewhere

@SimonMourier As far as I can tell, it is registered correctly, the program looks to be x64 in task manager, by client, do you mean Excel? Because if so, excel is x64. And yes, the error is class not registered.
